# PHP preg_replace is replacing too much

Tags: php, preg-replace

Code:

```
$string = "ABCD BEGIN LOL END ABCD";
$result = preg_replace("/BEGIN (.*?) END/","XD",$string);
```

Returns: `ABCD XD ABCD`, but I want to return `ABCD BEGIN XD END ABCD`,

How to do this correctly?

Comment: Format begin and end as lookbehind and lookahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind and lookahead:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(?<=BEGIN )(.*?)(?= END)/","XD",$string);
```

Comment: This is the best pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use it like follows**

```
$string = "ABCD BEGIN LOL END ABCD";
$result = preg_replace("/LOL/","XD",$string);
```

Comment: if i would make something simple like that, i would use just str_replace ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple capture groups and reinsert some content in your replacement:

```
<?php

$string = "ABCD BEGIN LOL END ABCD";
$result = preg_replace("/(BEGIN\s)(.*)(\sEND)/","$1XD$3",$string);
//Output is: ABCD BEGIN XD END ABCD
?>
```

Comment: I think "$1XD$3" is not universal. For example: in foreach with different patterns.

Comment: You are right, the pattern with lookaheads is much better, but that don't want to come in my mind first :D

But in the special case provided it should work!